# How to defeat an active Digglet Pokemon when oppenent has an additional on bench

Tags: pokemon

The Digglet from XY - Evolutions protects itself as long as it's on the bench. How is it possible to defeat the active Diglett if there's also a second one on the bench, causing each to protect itself?

[image]

Comment: I don't recognize that pokemon (and thus can't find the card). Can you find an image of the card online, or post the text of the card so we have something to reference. The closest I can find is Digglet, and there are many versions of the one so we would need to know which one you are talking about.

Comment: Also if you could talk about why this combination seems so difficult to beat that would be helpful.

Comment: From what I know, every pokemon in the TCG has several different cards. You would need to specify which one are you mentioning.

Comment: @diego  please review the image added

Answer (score 15):

**Diglett** card from **XY - Evolutions** expansion has an interesting ability:

> **Ability: Submerge**
>   As long as this Pokémon is on your Bench, prevent all damage done to this Pokémon by attacks *(both yours and your opponent's)*.

The phrase ***this Pokémon*** is special in Pokémon TCG - it refers to this one and only particular Pokémon, not any other, not even other Pokémon of the same species.

Thus it's quite simple to defeat two Digletts, because the active one can be damaged without problems. Just knock out the first one during one turn, then the second one during later turn.

[image: Diglett]

Comment: Nice work, finding the essence of the question and coming up with a good answer!